# shopping cart system and calculating total price

Tags: c#, asp-classic

I want to integrate online booking and payment system in my website.I have gone through differnt papers of shopping cart in google but I couldnot be clear from any of that.Till now I have created one table in database which includes session_id and dat product_id.When user clicks to add to cart it will be stored in that table.I have also created till view shopping cart but now my problem is how to calculate total price and where to keep that total column in database.As I researched now I need to create one table which include all the information along with total price of that user or session in database but I dont know when to insert in that table and how to take which users have booked it.I have in huge dilemma.Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a hint. You will have to use two tables for that.

```
Master Table - For storing common information (BillNo,Date,GradTotal,BillDiscount,etc).
Details Table - For storing information about each purchased item (ItemNo,UnitPrice,NetAmount,etc).
```

When an item is selected, insert that item to Details Table and then update GrandTotal in Master Table.

Comment: When to update in master table and more importantly when to insert in master table coz we insert only in details table when any item is selected. Thankyou for your answer.

Comment: When each item is selected, update MasterTable and set GrandTotal=sum(NetAmount) of DetailsTable. Other details (BillNo,Date,etc) can be inserted either at the time of payment or when the first item is selected.

Comment: When users delete the selected items then do it need to delete from both table?And I have sessionid that is guid created by system in master table now when to take userid in details table because I need to know which users have booked because only registered users are allowed to book in my system.

Comment: When user deletes an item, then that item should be delete from the DetailsTable and then update the MasterTable(GrandTotal).